# Compose TextField with blinking cursor and without the system's keyboard

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is it possible to use the `BasicTextField` without the system's keyboard showing when it is on focus (I have my own custom keyboard onscreen)?

I tried setting the `readOnly = true`. The system's keyboard is not shown, but the blinking cursor isn't either.

Comment: Check the [updated code and video](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72452258/9636037). The key logic is still the same. If it is still not working provide your code. We can't debug your issue without your code. The problem asked in the question is solved in the [provided answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72452258/9636037).

Answer (score 0):

The key to achieving this is to use `LocalSoftwareKeyboardController` and `FocusRequester` in combination.

First, focus on the `TextField` using `FocusRequester` and then hide the soft keyboard.

```
val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
val focusRequester = remember {
    FocusRequester()
}

LaunchedEffect(
    key1 = Unit,
) {
    focusRequester.requestFocus()
    keyboardController?.hide()
}
```

**Sample code**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun FocusedTextFieldWithoutKeyboard() {
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val focusRequester = remember {
        FocusRequester()
    }

    LaunchedEffect(
        key1 = Unit,
    ) {
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
        keyboardController?.hide()
    }

    val initialText = "Sample Text"
    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            value = TextFieldValue(
                text = "Sample Text",
                selection = TextRange(
                    start = initialText.length,
                    end = initialText.length,
                ),
            ),
        )
    }

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        Box {
            BasicTextField(
                value = text,
                onValueChange = { value: TextFieldValue ->
                    text = value
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .focusRequester(focusRequester),
                singleLine = true,
            )
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .matchParentSize()
                    .alpha(0f)
                    .clickable(
                        onClick = {},
                    ),
            )
        }
        Row {
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    text = text.copy(
                        text = "${text.text}1",
                        selection = TextRange(
                            start = text.text.length + 1,
                            end = text.text.length + 1,
                        ),
                    )
                },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp),
            ) {
                Text(text = "1")
            }
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    text = text.copy(
                        text = "${text.text}2",
                        selection = TextRange(
                            start = text.text.length + 1,
                            end = text.text.length + 1,
                        ),
                    )
                },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp),
            ) {
                Text(text = "2")
            }
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    text = text.copy(
                        text = "${text.text}3",
                        selection = TextRange(
                            start = text.text.length + 1,
                            end = text.text.length + 1,
                        ),
                    )
                },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp),
            ) {
                Text(text = "3")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Video]

Comment: Thanks for the reply : ). I tried that solution, but the keyboard is being opened when I launch the screen =/. It's also opening when I click on the TextField again.